# How do I adjust the space between x-ticks in a seaborn plot?

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot some data in a seaborn scatterplot. I have numerical values for y and strings for x, only two. When I plot them, it makes the two xticks very far apart. I tried a whole bunch of chatGPT "solutions", but to no avail. I would like the points to be closer together and further from the border of the plot. Any advice? Thanks.

I have tried using the stripplot, but I woudl like to make each categroy have a different marker, not color, and that seems to complicate the use of stripplot.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as numpy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

cm_data = pd.read_csv('cm_data_for_plots.csv')
cm_data


sns.scatterplot(data= cm_data, x= cm_data['feature'], y = cm_data['sa'], hue= cm_data['cave'])
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('Sa $(\mu m)$')
plt.legend(title = '')
```

This resulted in the following:

[image]

Comment: a dirty trick would be to use `plt.xlim()`

Comment: `sns.stripplot(...)` or `sns.swarmplot(...)` could be interesting here. These functions automatically add more margin, and spread out values that would be close together in a scatter plot. Or, `sns.lineplot()`, which would connect the values via a line.  E.g. `sns.lineplot(data=cm_data, x='feature', y='sa', hue='cave', marker='o', ls=':')`. Or `sns.pointplot(data=cm_data, x='feature', y='sa', hue='cave', marker='o', ls=':')`

Comment: @JohanC I'm pretty sure there's an existing answer for this.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Maybe you're referring to something like [reduce space between bars without changing width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209867/reduce-space-between-bars-without-changing-width)?

Comment: @JohanC I think that's one that I was think of for you. I think I also answered a similar one, but wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this:

```
data = {
    'feature': np.random.rand(100)>0.5,  # categorical if higher than 0.5, should give 50/50
    'sa': np.random.rand(100) * 10,  # some random data
    'cave': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], size=100)  # also something to control the colour
}
cm_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
cm_data['feature'] = cm_data['feature'].replace({True: "Mechanical", False: "Solutional"})

plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(data=cm_data, x='feature', y='sa', hue='cave')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('Sa $(\mu m)$')
plt.xlim((-2,3)) # basically use what you want, the two ticks will be at 0 and 1
plt.show()
```

Results with `plt.xlim((-2,3))`:

[image: -2, 3]

Results with `plt.xlim((-1,2))`

[image: -1, 2]

Comment: Another option is `plt.margins(x=0.3)` with the benefit that you don't need to know the x-values.

Comment: Both the plt.xlim() and plt.margins() solutions seemed to work the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: @JohanC definitely a much better approach!